# React - Show button in just one tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component with some buttons and tabs. I would like the buttons to NOT appear in one of those tabs. This seems rather simple, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Please consider this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from '../components';

class Parent extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        editMode: false, 
        showButtons: true
    }
}

showEditOption = () => { this.setState({ editMode: true }) }
hideEditOption = () => { this.setState({ editMode: false}) }

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div title="Company">
                {this.state.showButtons 
                ? !this.state.editMode ?
                    <button onClick={this.showEditOption}>Edit</button>
                    :
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <button onClick={this.hideEditOption} >Cancel</button>
                        <button disabled={disabled} onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} >Save</button>
                    </React.Fragment>
                : null 
                }
            </div>

            <Tabs startingKey="company" className={styles.tabs}>
                <Tab label='company' key='company'>
                    content 1 // show buttons here
                </Tab>
                <Tab label='users' key='users'>
                    content 2 // and not here
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

}
```

How can I achieve this? 
Thank you :)

Comment: Not clear what are trying to do.

Comment: You can simply pass a prop with something like showButtons and put the ternary condition on your main div just like the one you used with editMode.

Comment: Could you provide an example, @Kamesh?

Comment: Can you post a more clear scenario of your components? Which is your parent component and which one is your tab component?

Comment: I updated the code @Kamesh

Comment: `tabs` and `tab` aren't standard HTML elements - are they React components imported from some other file? If so, they should start with a capital letter.

Comment: They are custom react components

Comment: Can you also post your tab component? Because the buttons you are trying to hide must be in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am assuming what you wanted to say was that you have a button outside your tabs element and you want to show those buttons only when one tab was selected.

I would store the selected tab in state somewhere:

```
this.state = {
  editMode: false,
  showButtons: true,
  selectedTab: ''
}
```

Show the buttons only when the particular tab is selected:

```
 {this.state.showButtons && this.state.selectedTab === 'company'
        ? !this.state.editMode ?
          <button onClick={this.showEditOption}>Edit</button>
          :
          <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={this.hideEditOption} >Cancel</button>
            <button disabled={disabled} onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} >Save</button>
          </React.Fragment>
        : null
      }
```

Finally modify `Tabs` element to change state on tab change:

```
<Tabs startingKey="company" className={styles.tabs} onSelect={key => this.setState({ selectedTab: key })} >
```

Hope this was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a property to tell if the button is visible or not. When you create your component pass the 'isNotVisible' property

```
constructor(props){
  this.state = {
    editMode: false
  }
}
{if(!this.props.isNotVisible){ 
`<div title="Company">
  {this.state.editMode 
  ? <button>edit</button>
  : <button>cancel</button>
    <button>save</button>}
</div>

<tabs>
  <tab>content of tab 1</tab> // I want the buttons to appear here
  <tab>content of tab 2</tab> // and not here
</tabs>
`}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use click handlers on the tabs, then conditionally show or hide the content for each tab:

```
const Tabs = props => {
  const { children } = props;

  return <div className='tabs'>{children}</div>;
};

const Tab = props => {
  const { children, clickHandler } = props;

  return <div onClick={clickHandler} className='tab'>{children}</div>;
};

const TabContent = props => {
  const { children, show } = props;

  return show ? <div className='tabContent'>{children}</div> : null;
};

const App = props => {
  const [ tabIdx, setTabIdx ] = useState(0);
  const switchTab = tabIdx => setTabIdx(tabIdx);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Tabs>
        <Tab clickHandler={() => switchTab(0)}>
          First tab
        </Tab>
        <Tab clickHandler={() => switchTab(1)}>
          Second tab
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
      <TabContent show={tabIdx === 0}>
        First content
      </TabContent>
      <TabContent show={tabIdx === 1}>
        Second content
      </TabContent>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Or if you prefer, the same idea using a class component instead of the new Hooks syntax:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { tabIdx: 0 };

  switchTab = tabIdx => this.setState({ tabIdx });

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tabs>
          <Tab clickHandler={() => this.switchTab(0)}>
            First tab
          </Tab>
          <Tab clickHandler={() => this.switchTab(1)}>
            Second tab
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <TabContent show={this.state.tabIdx === 0}>
          First content
        </TabContent>
        <TabContent show={this.state.tabIdx === 1}>
          Second content
        </TabContent>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

};
```

For a more involved solution, I'd recommend using a router, such as [Reach Router](https://reach.tech/router/example/basic). Routers handle both what's rendered/displayed and also the URL path (so you'd have dedicated `/tab1` and `/tab2` paths, or whatever you chose to call them).

Answer (score 0):

for the buttons not to be shown on one of the tab put event handling on such a way that when you navigate to tab which needs not to show buttons, you simultaneously change the state of showing buttons to false